# How do I send data to a nodeJS websocket on the command line?

Tags: node.js, sockets, command-line, websocket

I have a node JS web socket server that is setup like so

```
// Miner Proxy Srv
var srv = new WebSocket.Server({
    server: web,
    path: "/proxy",
    maxPayload: 1024
});
srv.on('connection', (ws) => {
    var conn = {
        uid: null,
        pid: crypto.randomBytes(12).toString("hex"),
        workerId: null,
        found: 0,
        accepted: 0,
        ws: ws,
        pl: new net.Socket(),
    }
```

My question is how do I connect to the web socket AND send data to it?  I downloaded "wscat" and tried the below

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8000/proxy -p 13 -H "Host:localhost.localdomain.com" -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" '{"type":"auth","params":{"site_key":{"IF_EXCLUSIVE_TAB":"ifExclusiveTab","FORCE_EXCLUSIVE_TAB":"forceExclusiveTab","FORCE_MULTI_TAB":"forceMultiTab","CONFIG":{"LIB_URL":"https://localhost.localdomain.com/lib/","WEBSOCKET_SHARDS":[["wss://localhost.localdomain.com/proxy"]]},"CRYPTONIGHT_WORKER_BLOB":"blob:https://localhost.localdomain.com/54f39ac6-5c2a-4ff1-8052-c4e0e508034c"},"type":"anonymous","user":null,"goal":0}}'
```

but I get the error

```
error: Error: invalid server key
```

when I run the above.

Comment: did you try the solution? I was curious if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wscat` generates valid header `Sec-WebSocket-Key` for the request by default, so just remove `-H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ=="` from the command-line and it might work. I debugged on and found below header are already created even if I dont pass them through command-line using `wscat`.

```
srv.on('connection', (ws,req) => {
    console.log(req.headers);
     /*
     //headers present without passing arguments to wscat
     { 'sec-websocket-version': '13',
       'sec-websocket-key': 's3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=',
        connection: 'Upgrade',
        upgrade: 'websocket',

        .....
     */
     ......
```

So use following command:

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8000/proxy -p 13 -H "Host:localhost.localdomain.com" -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" '{"type":"auth","params":{"site_key":{"IF_EXCLUSIVE_TAB":"ifExclusiveTab","FORCE_EXCLUSIVE_TAB":"forceExclusiveTab","FORCE_MULTI_TAB":"forceMultiTab","CONFIG":{"LIB_URL":"https://localhost.localdomain.com/lib/","WEBSOCKET_SHARDS":[["wss://localhost.localdomain.com/proxy"]]},"CRYPTONIGHT_WORKER_BLOB":"blob:https://localhost.localdomain.com/54f39ac6-5c2a-4ff1-8052-c4e0e508034c"},"type":"anonymous","user":null,"goal":0}}'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't take the data that I wanted to send to the web socket, but it did get me to a command line mode (responded with "connected (press CTRL+C to quit)") that allowed me to type in data to send to the web socket.